# Two similar requests, how to improve?

Tags: vue.js, vue-composition-api

I have two requests to the server. The first one at the initial rendering of the page, the second one - by the "Show more" button.

**request 1:**

```
const getAllNews = () => {
 fetch(`${BASE_URL}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    allNews.value = data.items
    totalPages.value = data.nav.total
  })
 .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

**request 2:**

```
const fetchMore = () => {
 currentPage.value += 1
 fetch(`${BASE_URL}/${currentPage.value}/`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
   allNews.value = data.items
   totalPages.value = data.nav.total
   })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

There is code duplication here, what should be used in order to optimize this code?

Comment: Hi there! StackOverflow is usually to help you with the "how" not the "what". What issue did you face when trying to refractor this code?

Comment: This is subjective but not all code duplication needs to be "fixed" or optimized.  Especially not for the small amount of code in question.  You could combine the methods by adding some parameter and some `if` statements to handle the two different cases, but readability would probably go down. Sometimes allowing a small amount of duplicate code for readability is a fair trade-off. It's definitely not a black and white issue, or one that has a definite answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract a (global?) function that fetches data from your api:

```
const fetchData = (uri = "") => fetch(`${BASE_URL}${uri}`)
  .then(response => response.json());
```

For the update, you can have a local function:

```
const updateData = data => {
  allNews.value = data.items;
  totalPages.value = data.nav.total
};
```

You might also want to extract your error handling logic if it's shared:

```
const handleError = err => console.error(err);
```

And with these two you can rewrite your functions:

```
const getAllNews = () =>
  fetchData("/")
    .then(updateData)
    .catch(handleError);

const fetchMore = () => {
  currentPage.value += 1
  return fetchData(`/${currentPage.value}/`)
    .then(updateData)
    .catch(handleError);
}
```